# How could the following code be written in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, variables, razor

How could the following code be written in Javascript? I wish to declare a variable which could be accessed in any pages.It's possible for me to declare a variable as follow in the razor code but I have no idea how may I write it in the javascript. Is it possible to declare such variable in javascript?

```
@{

 App.VariableName = "some string values";
}
```

Comment: You can't, and it's that easy as there is no notion of state in javascript (in a browser enviroment)

Comment: Cookies and local storage come to mind

Comment: You could put it in a script that you include on all your pages.

Comment: @adeneo it can be done by using a master and declaring this variable which will be available for each page that target this master page.

Comment: @cubitouch - that would rely on .ASP masterpages, not javascript, to keep the state.

Comment: @adeneo He is talking about Razor, which is an ASP.NET MVC application right ? (by master I mean parent template) EDIT : My bad, I didn't understood the question, I thought using HTML/JS instead of Razor.

Comment: He has .ASP code, that is global, and is asking how to write it in javascipt, but there is no "global" across HTTP requests in javascript, unless you store the value somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

> I wish to declare a variable which could be accessed in any pages.

If you mean, any pages *in your site/app*, you can use [web storage](http://www.w3.org/TR/webstorage/): Local storage if the values should endure between sessions, or session storage if not.

If you just want to store a string, that's simple:

```
// Setting the string, whenever you want to remember it
localStorage.variableName = "some string";

// Getting the string, probably on page load
var theString = localStorage.variableName;
// `theString` will be `null` if `variableName` didn't exist in storage
// for this site
```

These are limited to strings, so people usually combine them with JSON. On page load:

```
var storedStuff = JSON.parse(localStorage.myStuff || "null") || {
    // Default values here for when we don't have stored stuff yet
    variableName: "some stuff"
};
```

Then whenever you change `storedStuff.variableName` (or whenever you want to save that change):

```
localStorage.myStuff = JSON.stringify(storedStuff);
```

For session storage instead, just change `localStorage` above to `sessionStorage`.

---

The idiom

```
var storedStuff = JSON.parse(localStorage.myStuff || "null") || {
    // Default values here for when we don't have stored stuff yet
    variableName: "some stuff"
};
```

could probably use some explaining:

1. If we try to retrieve something that doesn't exist in local storage, we get back `null`. JavaScript has a [curiously-powerful `||` operator](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/02/javascripts-curiously-powerful-or.html): Rather than returning a boolean value, it returns the left-hand argument if that argument is truthy, and its right-hand argument otherwise. So `localStorage.myStuff || "null"` will be the string from local storage, or if there isn't one, the string `"null"`.
2. We then parse the result, which is either a serialized array we stored earlier, or the string `"null"`. Although the string `"null"` wouldn't be a valid JSON document, it *is* a valid JSON *fragment*, and `JSON.parse` is documented to accept fragments. So the result of the parsing is either the array we stored previously, or `null`.
3. Then we use the curiously-powerful `||` operator again to choose between the deserialized result and an object with our defaults in it (`{...}`). So if we deserialized `null`, we'll choose the object with our defaults; if we deserialized an object, we'll choose that.

Comment: may I know how can I do that? Is there any sample code which I can refer to? Thx a lot! :)

I mean to declare a variable which could be accessed in any pages in my site/app

Comment: thx ya! I think I have to spend some time on digesting it~ :)

Comment: @user3156931: I added a simple string example, since you just said you wanted a string. I kinda went OTT with the JSON... :-)

Comment: so, what if I wish to retrieve the localstorage variable in razor?

Comment: @user3156931: Maybe I've misunderstood the question, I thought you wanted to do this all on the client. If you want the variable stored server-side in Razor, you wouldn't store it in web storage at all. You'd do [something like this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5292846/157247) to have Razor send the variable to the browser. That's one-way, though. To send it back, you'd have to use ajax. (I think, I don't know Razor, but a quick search suggests that's the case...)

Comment: I see, actually what I am trying to is to get the id of the image which is clicked and pass the id to another page. 

Therefore, I wish to store the id in such a way that I can get it on another page. May I know how could it be done?

Comment: @user3156931: Do you want the information client-side or server-side?

Comment: I get the id of img when it's clicked on client side and now trying to pass to the server side of another page, is it possible?

as the id of the img will be used as a key to retrieve the data from my SQL database.

Comment: @user3156931 That's not what your question is asking. To do that you simply need to submit the ID from the image via ajax or a direct http request.

Answer (score 0):

If your browser supports it you can use localStorage or sessionStorage to store variables between pages - See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage for details and compatibility table.

Can be used as so:

```
localStorage["mydata"] = myvariable;
var dataFromStorage = localStorage["mydata"];
```

Local storage will persist the data after you close the browser, session storage will only last for that browser session.

Comment: may I know how may I access the localStorage in razor ?